# Starting a numerical differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, programming

I need to solve an equation that looks rougly like:
$$ y(t) = y(t-1) + y(t-2) + u(t) $$
I have $u(t)$ and programming this solution is quite straightforward i.e.:

```
for t,i in enumerate(u):
    y[t] = y[t-1] + y[t-2] + u[t]
```

Should do the job, my problem is just the first two data points, what is the 'correct' way to input those, I was thinking to use `y(1) = u(1)` and `y(2) = y(1)+ u(2)` and take it from there, but am not sure if this is 'allowed'.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the code that it is executable, `u` can not at the same time be array and function. // And yes, usually one needs two initial conditions or two boundary conditions. One convention in controlled systems is indeed to set $y(t)=0$ for $t<0$, which would result in your initialization.

Comment: You're right it should be `u[t]` to indicate the location in the Array (edited).  Thank you, than I know I'm doing something logical.